# get_results suddenly not working on a single table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a list of rows from the DB. All tables work except the one I need. No errors are thrown, don't even get a blank array. My SELECT statement works fine in phpmyadmin directly, but not through Wordpress.

Any ideas what might be going on? Its driving me nuts.

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  properties")
```

Comment: What mysql_error() saing you? Have you check/add/remove any query filters that can change your query?

Comment: Please add the SELECT statement to your question to make answers possible.

Comment: I added the query, its super basic. I'm literally just getting everything from that table. It's not a WP specific table, but I'm accessing it so I can import it into WP. All my other non-wp tables work fine, just not that one. There is data in it for sure, I've tried renaming it but I just get nothing. No errors, no results. If I misspell the table name, I get an error like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the query result to a variable?

`$resultArray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  properties")`

Comment: Yeah that'a actually what I've been doing.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you included will work provided that `$wpdb` has been declared and `properties` is a table in your WordPress database.

I advise testing your query separately with [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) or [Debug Bar Console](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-console/)

For example, I ran the code below in the Debug Bar Console

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  properties" ) or die( mysql_error() );
print_r( $result );
```

The output returns the two rows in my `properties` table:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [key] => 1 [number] => 100 ) [1] => stdClass Object
([key] => 2 [number] => 200 ) )
```